# getting last image from post

Tags: php, wordpress

Looking to add to my DOM code to include targeting the last image of my wordpress posts

EDIT - the code I have only targets/pulls out the blockquote of the content. I want to be able to use the last image in my wordpress post as a background for specific div.

html

```
<?php
    $content = get_the_content();
    $content = wpautop($content);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(get_the_content(), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    foreach ($xpath->query('//blockquote') as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }

   // My attempt 
   foreach ($xpath->query('//img') as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }   

    $content = $doc->saveHTML($doc);            
?>
```

My attempt has been able to remove the images altogether not target the last one.

Comment: Good for you! ___But is there a question in here somewhere?___ Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry I guess my intro sentence was specific enough, I want to add to this code to include targeting the last image of the post. It currently targets and pulls out only the blockquote

Comment: Oh right now I understand. ___So go ahead and do just that___. If when you have had a go, it proves to much for you, come and show us what you have done and we will be more than willing to help. But for now SO is **not a free Coding  service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: added what I have tried in terms of what came closest to what I want

Answer (score 0):

Try `preg_match_all()`:

```
// Make sure shortcodes are fetched.
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

preg_match_all('/<img([^>]+)>/', $content, $images);

$last_image = array_pop($images[0]);
```

Comment: Originally I went down this route and found a working example. But I've been told countless times to do this type of thing with a DOM parser

Comment: is there a reason for using one over the other?